# Creating Windows Vista Aurora screensaver like curtain effect in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

I am trying to create an interactive background animation using WebGL / Three.js

- The animation would be generated from a two-color gradient
- The animation would be controlled by external factors (intensity, speed, etc.)

The result should look something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdrkrCFRHWA

I am not sure how Vista managed to pull the effect and I am interested in possible techniques which would yield similar looking results. I am looking for pointers how to get started

- Should I use alpha blended generated textures and dancing quads?
- Should I use pixel shaders?
- etc.

Any tips welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) and render a bunch of triangle strips and do the gradient effect itself on the fragment shader.

The effect looks rather simple enough to be wholly calculated inside the fragment shader directly, so a fullscreen quad would also work nicely. Depends really on the type of detail you are aiming for, I'd experiment with both.